# TFS Java SDK - Oauth credentials

Tags: security, tfs, ldap, omniauth

I have tfs server and I expose nice interface for the users login and perform operations on the TFS Server.

The tfs sdk requires me to write the username and password as plain text, I get the password of the current user only on sign-in for ldap authentication (this is a ruby on rails app using omniauth-ldap).

How can i authenticate securely? without saving the password as plain-text? (which is currently what I am doing)..

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TFS are you using? If you are using TFS 2012 take a look at digest authentication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833874(v=vs.110).aspx